# LWJGL Demo GLXGears requires a demo package

Tags: java, kotlin, lwjgl

The LWJGL [GLXGears](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/GLXGears.java) example requires `import static org.lwjgl.demo.util.IOUtil.*`

I tried adding `implementation 'com.github.LWJGL:lwjgl3-demos:-SNAPSHOT'` to my build.gradle but it doesn't seem to do anything.

What should I do to get the example working?

Comment: @httpdigest So you are saying there is no way to make it work without downloading the source of the demo project?

Comment: @httpdigest Can you post an answer then please?